# Can not get Keyboard in android

Tags: android

I create *EditText*. How to get *Keyboard* object and set myself setting. For example set first letter in upper case when I focused on *EditText*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add 'android:inputType="textCapSentences"' to you EditText element in you XML layout. as example:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"/>
```

It could not be applied automatically on a Emulator like GenyMotion, but if you test it on a device it would.

Good luck